# Code First Database Class Generation

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6

I am using the Entity Data Model Wizard/ Code First From  Database option.

I want a Model class for each table below (Action, ActionDefs, etc). What am I doing wrong? I get the following:

[image]

```
public partial class MyDBContext : DbContext
{
    public MyDBContext()
        : base("name=MyDBContext")
    {
    }

    public virtual DbSet<Action> Actions { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<ActionDef> ActionDefs { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<ActionMethod> ActionMethods { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Activation> Activations { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Address> Addresses { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<AdHocComCall> AdHocComCalls { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<AdHocComFunction> AdHocComFunctions { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<AdHocComParam> AdHocComParams { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<AdHocDetail> AdHocDetails { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<AdHocError> AdHocErrors { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<AdHocGroup> AdHocGroups { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<AdHocJoin> AdHocJoins { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<AdHocQuery> AdHocQueries { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Affiliation> Affiliations { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Answer> Answers { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<audiobook> audiobooks { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Audit> Audits { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<AutoLinkException> AutoLinkExceptions { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<AutoLinkQueue> AutoLinkQueues { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Billing> Billings { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<BillingExportHP> BillingExportHPs { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<BillingMethod> BillingMethods { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<CAM_IRAAccountUpdateQueue> CAM_IRAAccountUpdateQueue { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<CaseDetail1> CaseDetail1 { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<CaseDetail2> CaseDetail2 { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<CFGDate> CFGDates { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<CfgGeneric> CfgGenerics { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<CFGNumeric> CFGNumerics { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<CFResult> CFResults { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<CFResultsRaw> CFResultsRaws { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Client> Clients { get; set; }
```

Comment: Please clarify your question.  What are you doing to get the results you are currently getting?

Comment: I am doing the following

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj200620(v=vs.113).aspx

Comment: Was I clear? I wanted to generate the classes for each table listed above while doing Code First from database

Comment: You're not clear about what did and what didn't work. Your code shows a whole list of DbSet<>s that suggest the classes were generated.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, but I'm not sure how it works. 
1) Code First From Database option.
2) Delete Above
3) EF Designer from Database
4) Delete Above
5) Do #1 again.